# can't get info about logged in user

Tags: php, flickr

please can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here i can not get a nsid or
       user
      name with this code.
      i tried a lot of things other example code etc. but they all not working is it so 
      hard to get the logged in username or nsid,this code worked before,i already start 
      over 10 times with this, it worked then it doesn't so i start over.please help 
      me....

```
  <?php
 $api_key = "xxxxxxx";
 $secret = "xxxxxxxx";
 $perms = "write";
 $token = "xxxxxxxx";
 require 'phpflickr/phpflickr.php';
 // create login URL
 $loginUrl = $instagram->getLoginUrl();
 // receive OAuth code parameter
 $code = $_GET['code'];

 function login_link($api_key, $secret, $perms)
 {
      $sig_string = "{$secret}api_key{$api_key}perms{$perms}";
      $api_sig = md5($sig_string);
      $url = "http://flickr.com/services/auth?api_key={$api_key}&perms=
                   {$perms}&api_sig={$api_sig}";
      return $url;
}

$url = login_link($api_key, $secret, $perms);

/* FLICKR LOGIN LINK */
echo '<div id="flckrlogin"><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" 
             src="' . $url . '">Login to Flickr</a></div>';
 /* FLICKR LOGIN */




if(isset($_GET['frob'])){        
     $frob = $_GET['frob'];
     $_SESSION['frob'] = $_GET['frob']; 
} 
if(isset($_SESSION['frob'])) {     

} 
   function getResource($url)
   {
    $chandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($chandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($chandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($chandle);
    curl_close($chandle);
    return $result;
}

function logUit()
{
    $api_key = "";
    $secret = "";
}

function getToken($api_key, $secret, $frob)
{
    $method = "flickr.auth.getToken";
    $sig_string = "
                     {$secret}api_key{$api_key}frob{$frob}method{$method}";
    $api_sig =
        md5($sig_string);
    $token_url =
        "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?
                      method=flickr.auth.getToken&api_key={$api_key}&frob=
                      {$frob}&api_sig={$api_sig}";
    $feed = getResource($token_url);
    $rsp
        = simplexml_load_string($feed);
    return $rsp;
}

$token_rsp = getToken($api_key, $secret, $frob);
if ($token_rsp !== "") {
    $nsid = $token_rsp->auth->user["nsid"];

    $photos = $f->people_getPublicPhotos($nsid, NULL, NULL, 12);
    $username = $token_rsp->auth->user["username"];
    $auth_token = $token_rsp->auth->token;
    $perms = $token_rsp->auth->perms;
    echo "<div id='flckrlogin'><a href='?frob=' onclick='" . logUit() . "'>loguit..
                 .</a></div>";
    # display some user info
    echo $token_rsp->auth->user["fullname"], " loggedIn(Flickr)<br>";
}
function uploadPhoto($path, $title)
{
    $api_key = "xxxxxxxx";
    $secret = "xxxxxx";
    $perms = "write";
    $token = "xxxxxxxxx";
    $f = new phpFlickr("xxxxxxxxxx", $secret);
    return $f->async_upload($path, $title);
}

echo '<div id="flckrlogin"><a href="' . $url . '">Login to Flickr</a></div>';

?>
```

Comment: Why have a function in a if statement. Why is the indentation all over the place

Comment: ok i put it out of the if statement still not working and what do you mean by indentation.

Comment: @robert, do you see any error messages? If yes, could you add it in the text of your question? If no, have you tried to print intermidiate info? (for example, strings inside `getToken()`) Add more details in the question!

Comment: well the only error i get is trying to get property of nonobject on this line $nsid = $token_rsp->auth->user["nsid"]; and the next lines after that with the same operation.when i try var_dump($token_rsp) it says bool(false).when i use echo "ssssssss" inside gettoken it echo ssssssss

Comment: I am sure that you can access a dictionary. Just be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether the frob parameter is empty rather than `isset()`

```
if(!empty($_GET['frob'])){        
 $frob = $_GET['frob'];
 $_SESSION['frob'] = $_GET['frob']; 
} 
if(!empty($_SESSION['frob'])) {     

}
```

Comment: i think the frob is not empty, i see it in the url when it comes back after login its just after that i can't get any info on the screen,i tried several var_dumps in each function but it keeps saying bool(false) but i will try it.

Comment: ok youre code does it,it says frob is empty,but i get it in my return url so what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can you paste the URL parameters here, as you see them

Comment: the weird thing is that the last thing that i can get is the gettoken url with the api key the frob key and the api sig and after that all i get is bool(false) if i use var_dump.so it is going wrong with gettoken but i can't figure out where.